# How can i prevent objects faces clipping over other objects faces?

Tags: unity, 3d, shaders

[image]

I have a naked body, I have a bra over that body, I have a suit over that bra.

Since the objects arent accurate enough, i get ugly "clipping". 
Is there a way or method I can prevent this? (except messing with the Scale)

Like a shader which gives out a Render-Queue to faces near other faces... and does always render first ... if the rendered item is near enough.

Comment: Have you tried not rendering the Bra if a shirt is present?

Comment: @LukeG of course, - but then i have a the breasts clipping out.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to disable enable mesh renderers in order to make this work. I got into a similar problem way back, and i solved it using a shader. All it does is cull the part of the mesh not visible from the camera. Since i learned how to do this through a tutorial, i'll leave the link here:http://www.toxicfork.com/194/per-object-clipping-planes-shader-in-unity3d-5

Comment: though its not exactly what i had in mind, i surely could make it work somehow with lots of time and tweaking (since i have "round" objects like a "butt" and animated characters, so my clipping planes need to animated properly and so on.

thank you tho

Comment: No problem :). I'm sure that with a bit of tweaking you will achieve the desired result, at the end of the day, that's the funny part! Good luck